# How to delete and recreate a postgres database using a single docker command?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am writing a microservice application which has a docker container for postgres database. I know that when dumping SQL to database, we use this docker command in terminal:

`cat <dump sql file> | docker exec -i <container ID> psql -U <postgres username> <database name>`

I was wondering if there is a similar linux terminal docker command that i can run from outside the container to:

1. Create database named
2. Drop database named

Or even:

3. Delete all tables of the  to make it completely empty in one command.

Note that i should be able to run the docker command from outside the container through the host OS terminal (linux).

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where your question has `cat <dump sql file>` you can put anything you want that prints out SQL commands on stdout; that includes `echo DROP DATABASE ...`.

Remember that you can use an ordinary PostgreSQL client to interact with a PostgreSQL server, regardless of whether or not it's running in Docker.  (This does require you to have published the database port externally, usually with a `docker run -p5432:5432` option or similar.)  You do not need root-level access on the host, or a root shell on the database server, just to run database commands.

This shell command will drop a named database on a PostgreSQL instance running on the current host; or if it's not on the current host or on the default port, you can [set `PGHOST` and `PGPORT` environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/libpq-envars.html).

```sh
export PGHOST=localhost
# export PGUSER=<postgres username>
# export PGDATABASE=<database name>
echo "DROP DATABASE $1" | psql
```

Answer (score 45):

is the Postgres storage local to the container? If so, then removing the container and recreating it will reset your DB in itself. If your data is mounted from a local or network folder, then reseting it means running commands on `psql`

You have several options:

- get inside the container with a shell

`docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/sh`

and then run psql and do whatever you want inside the psql command line.

- run psql directly in docker

`docker exec -it <container-id> psql -U <username> -d <database-name>`

- have psql installed locally and run it to access the postgres instance in docker

`psql -U <username> -h localhost`

- run the commands with psql

You cannot DROP and CREATE a database on the same command unfortunately, but you can run 2 separate commands

`docker exec -it <container-id> psql -U <username> -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE <dbname>;"`

`docker exec -it <container-id> psql -U <username> -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE <dbname>;"`

Comment: @sshussain270 please change accepted answer :) to this ;)

Answer (score 5):

A bit ugly, but one liner is also possible :

1. Find out id of docker container

```sh
docker ps | grep postgres | awk '{print $1}'
```

2. Paste it in command from post above

```sh
docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep postgres | awk '{print $1}') psql -U postgres -d postgres -с $command
```

3. We cannot DROP and CREATE a database on the same command, but we can run two times using for loop in bash )

```sh
for command in 'delete dbname' 'create dbname'; do echo $command; done
```

4. Finally let's compile it together in one liner:

```sh
for command in 'drop database metrics;' 'create database metrics;'; do docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep postgres | awk '{print $1}') psql -U postgres -d postgres -c $command; done
```

PS 'metrics' - database name just an example and you should use yours :)